# How to test the status code when key headers are valid

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I wanted to test the status code if all the key headers are valid.
All I know is the Content-type key. I'm getting an error when doing this to other key headers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var headers =pm.request.headers.toObject()
console.log(headers)
```

all headers send request can be accessed using above method in the test script

```
var headers = pm.request.headers.map()
console.log(headers.length)


_ = require("lodash")

let expectedHeaders = ["Accept","Content-Type"]

let requiredHeaders =_.filter(headers, function (n) {
    return expectedHeaders.includes(n.key);
});



_.isEqual(requiredHeaders.map(n=>n.key).sort(), expectedHeaders.sort()) ?  pm.test("sometest",function(){
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.eql(200)
}):null
```

is here we are filtering out required headers and validating that all headers are present as expected and the running a test if the header is as expected else doing nothing